# Return a function for IF ELSE IF statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to run a block of code that is series of IF ELSE IF statements, that checks to see if certain conditions are true.

```
    if (2 > 1) {
        return true;
    }

    else if (3 > 1) {
        return true;
    }

    else if (4 > 1) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        alert('Not all conditions are true')
    }
```

It is working fine, but I want to add a function at the end, if all the conditions are true, In the code below I added the function, but now it seems to run the function without checking all the conditions first

```
    if (2 > 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (3 > 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (4 > 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Not all conditions are true')
    }

    // Run this function after checking all the conditions are true
    allConditionsTrue();
```

I think I am getting confused with where the function should be placed.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you `return true` in each successful test, you never get to `allConditionsTrue()`. You also won't check all of the conditions.

Comment: The function is written outside, so obviously it will call, instead of that write a function wrap all you if else condition inside it and invoke the function

Comment: It's not clear what you're describing.  If *any* of the conditions are true then the function won't be called because you're returning.  And even if you don't return, you're not checking if *all* conditions are true because as soon as one is true the rest aren't examined.

Comment: You will not execute anything after a return - perhaps you mean
`function something() {
  if (2 > 1 && 3 > 1 && 4 > 1) {
    allConditionsTrue();
  } else {
    alert('Not all conditions are true')
  }
}`

Comment: place the function within the condition - which after all is what your example suggests is your intention.  :).

Comment: Can you share the wrapper function as well?

Comment: @crashmstr yep I totally realised after you pointed it out!

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Yes thank you for your input, that is another thing wrong with my approach I gathered

Comment: @David Thank you, yes you are correct, I am getting my head around what I was expecting and what is actually happening!

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for taking the time to write this function, this works!

Comment: @BrianPeacock yes totally!

Comment: @AadilMehraj I don't have a wrapper function buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an arbitrary count of condition and with an immediate exit if one previous condition is `false` and the next is `true`, you could take a variable for the state if `someFalse` value occurs.

Afetr checkin all conditions check `someFalse` and return with `'Not all conditions are true'`.

Finally it is clear, that all conditions are `true` and you can call a function for this case.

```js
function check(value) {
    function allConditionsTrue() {
        console.log('All conditions are true');
    }
    
    let someFalse = false,
        conditions = [value < 2, value < 3, value < 4],
        fn = c => c ? someFalse : !(someFalse = true);

    if (conditions.some(fn)) return true;

    if (someFalse) {
        console.log('Not all conditions are true');
        return false;
    }
    
    allConditionsTrue();
    return true;
}

console.log(1, check(1));
console.log(2, check(2));
console.log(3, check(3));
console.log(4, check(4));
```

Comment: this really helped me, as I was able to refactor my approach like everyone has said, this answer allowed me to approach it in a way I wouldn't have thought about!

Comment: Isn't someFalse supposed to be allFalse?

Comment: no. i mean yes, in the later view, but in first it changes if one condition is `false` and because of the next `true` value in `conditions`, it is used then to exit `some` which ends the function as well.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at && (AND) and || (OR) operators:

```
 if (2>1 && 3>1 && 4>1) {  
      allConditionsTrue(); 
      return true; 
   } else { 
     alert('not all conditions true'); 
   }
```

Comment: What qualifies a "real" question? It is a very basic question, true, but he still needed help and elaborated his approach.

Comment: So I am not the only one to think it's not worth answering.
What defines a "real" question? One that shows the asker throught about what was going on. The question above is so basic boolean logic, it does not really need to be asked at SO. But now it has been asked and the comments answered it

Answer (score -1):

You placed the function call outside of all the checks so it is independent of the conditions. You can give it its own if block like:

```js
if (2 > 1 && 3 > 1 && 4 > 1) {
  allConditionsTrue()
}
```

Or if you don't want to rewrite all the checks then you can create an array to hold their respective values like

```js
let conds = [false, false, false]
if (2 > 1) {
    conds[0] = true
}
if (3 > 1) {
    conds[1] = true
}
if (4 > 1) {
    conds[2] = true
}
if (!conds.some(v => !v)) { // all are true
    allConditionsTrue()
}
if (conds.some(v => v)) {
    return true
} else {
    alert('Not all conditions are true')
}
```

Edit: corrected with suggestion from comment

Edit 2: an improvement

Comment: Why have some twice?

Comment: The first checks if all the conditions are true, but the second checks if at least one is.